# Could multiple PCIe devices in one IOMMU group be added to different KVM VM separately?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, pcie

I want to know could multiple PCIe devices in one IOMMU group be added to different KVM VM separately?

I have got failed message like "card1 is used by VM1, and card2 is in the card1's group and added to VM2, then VM2 can't boot"

I have tried vfio driver, but didn't work, so what should I do? try SR-IOV? or update KVM-QEMU or update the kernel?

Motherboard: ASUS 390-A(intel supports VT-D)
Host OS: Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 4.18.0-15
KVM-QEMU: version 2.11.1

Comment: Could you provide more details? Why are the devices you need on the same group? Is SR-IOV an option? Generally you can't assign different devices of the same group to different VMs, but maybe you can make them be part of different groups.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: *you shouldn't but can try to fake/force the system into it*

Having the devices in the same group is a deficiency of the HW/FW that you use for the use-case that you want to achieve. Guests using the different cards can effectively read/write each others memory (more complex in reality but a nice simplification). That is very much not what you want from virtualization.

There are non upstream accepted patches around this which can help you to fake/force splitting some of these IOMMU groups. But really - please read what it does and understand the associated risks [here by the maintainer](https://vfio.blogspot.com/2014/08/iommu-groups-inside-and-out.html).

If you really want you can consider [compiling your own kernel with the patch](https://gist.github.com/mdPlusPlus/031ec2dac2295c9aaf1fc0b0e808e21a) and then use these boot parameters which can help then to (fake-)split the devices:

```
pcie_acs_override=downstream,multifunction
```

If you have multiple PCIe slots, moving around the cards is a much better (and safer) way to achieve the same.